# Can image alt text be set dynamically?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, alt

I have a question about making dynamically set images obey accessibility standards.

Technically, it is possible to set the image alt text with JavaScript.  However, when I "view source" of a page in which this is done, the alt text does not appear as an actual image attribute.  If I set the title attribute using JavaScript, the tool tip works, showing that as far as the browser is concerned, the title attribute is set.

So, would a screen reader, or other method a blind person would use to read the page, see the alt text that was set in JavaScript?

Here is an example:

```
<html>
    <script>
function set_image_properties(){
document.getElementById("image").src = "http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/free.jpeg";
document.getElementById("image").alt = "free";
document.getElementById("image").title = "free";
}
    </script>
    <body onload="set_image_properties()">
        <img id="image"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The developer tools needs a refresh, close and open the developer's tool to see the `alt`

Answer (score 4):

As long as the device which open your page has Javascript enabled the user will see the effect. However, this will not work for a search engine crawlers for example.